# How Can I Resize A Banner ID In Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityads

When I tried to add a banner Ad in Unity it is showing way too small. Is there any way to resize it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The size changes depending on device, mobile vs. tablet, for example.  But there are only two sizes. The placeholder isn't necessarily indicative of what it will look like live, unfortunately. Also, Unity doesn't provide any functionality to resize an ad. This is probably to prevent abuse and allow those purchasing ads to have expectations met. The ads are likely created at the two specific sizes.

Here's a unity forum link on the topic:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/banner-ad-size-on-higher-resolutions.812043/

In my research, it sounds like google admob allows more control over banner size.